# django Swagger can't add parameter descriptions

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger-2.0

I did the override according to the document but it still doesn't work.

These are document:
https://github.com/m-haziq/django-rest-swagger-docs#advance-usage
https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/549

This is my views.py

```
class JobIndustryOfJobViewSet(ModelViewSet):
"""
description: A viewset for viewing and editing industries of a job.
parameters:
  - name: job_pk
    type: string
    required: true
    location: path
"""

serializer_class = JobIndustryOfJobSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Filter by current user's client and parent object
    """
    job = get_object_or_404(
        get_job_queryset(self.request.user), pk=self.kwargs.get("job_pk")
    )
    return JobIndustry.objects.filter(job=job).select_related("industry")
```

And it still don't show the parameter descriptions in the Swagger UI

Django==2.2.1

djangorestframework==3.9.4

django-rest-swagger==2.2.0